# How to set class to child element inside v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I need some help, I have v-for loop which outputs elements of array referenceDetailsDocumentsData, I need to check at the same time if the id of this element exists in another array documentsData, in this case I need to add custom class to child of this element.

```js
<div class="loading-doc-item"
     v-for="referenceDetails in referenceDetailsDocumentsData"
     :key="referenceDetails.id">
    <div class="loading-doc-show">
        {{ referenceDetails.name }}
        <span class="upload-status" v-if="checkUploadedDocuments(referenceDetails.id)">
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
        </span>
        <span class="upload-status" v-else>
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

methods() {
    checkUploadedDocuments(id) {
        return this.documentsData.filter(item => item.id === id);
    }
}
```

In my case, I am getting an error

> Error in render: "TypeError: this.documentsData.filter is not a
> function"

Comment: I dont know why you're getting this filter error, but if you want to add class styles based on condition you should try class binding.

https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax

And check yout documentsData is a proper array type or not. Because filter function works with array type.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: this.documentsData mostly likely is not an array

Comment: Or the component may be trying to render before that data exists.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong - the method `checkUploadedDocuments` will return `Array` but it must return `Boolean`.

```
<div class="loading-doc-item"
 v-for="referenceDetails in referenceDetailsDocumentsData" :key="referenceDetails.id">
  <div class="loading-doc-show">
    {{ referenceDetails.name }}
    <span class="upload-status">
        <i class="fa" 
          :class="{documentsData && documentsData.length &&
            documentsData.findIndex(item => item.id === referenceDetails.id) !== -1 
            ? 'fa-check-circle' : 'fa-check'}"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```